# detect web crawler in site page in angular universal

Tags: angular, web-crawler, server-side-rendering, universal

I want to detect the current request for my page in server side rendered - `ssr` is from a web crawler or a normal user .
I want to do some things in web crawler and not to do when it's a user.
I want to run `ng-in-viewport` when web crawler is accessing the page to get complete data.
But not to run when user is using my page.
How to detect this thing ?

Comment: You can determine it by using 'User-agent' header. Example: "User-agent: Googlebot" for Google search engine.

Answer (score 8):

recently I faced the same challenge like you. I have SSR for my Angular app, and I use StateTransfer, to avoid making the same API calls in browser after user just saw rendered content from server.

I have a views counter, and since page is rendered on server side, I would like to avoid counting views made by crawlers.

So, what I end up with:

In `server.ts` (which is standard generated file for Angular SSR) ensure you're passing request object from express, I have it like this:

```js
server.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render(indexHtml, {
    req, // Express request
    res, // Express response
    providers: [
      { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl },
    ],
  });
});
```

Then in any `constants.ts` where you prefer to keep your constants, add `VIEWER` injection token and possible list of crawlers:

```js
export const VIEWER = new InjectionToken<string>('viewer');
export const CRAWLER_AGENTS = [
  'googlebot', 'yandexbot', 'yahoo', 'bingbot',
  'baiduspider', 'facebookexternalhit', 'twitterbot', 'rogerbot',
  'linkedinbot', 'embedly', 'quora link preview', 'showyoubot', 'outbrain',
  'pinterest/0.', 'developers.google.com/+/web/snippet',
  'slackbot', 'vkshare', 'w3c_validator', 'redditbot', 'applebot',
  'whatsapp', 'flipboard', 'tumblr', 'bitlybot', 'skypeuripreview',
  'nuzzel', 'discordbot', 'google page speed'
];
```

Then in my `app.module.ts` in providers I added new provider, which will contain information if this is bot or user:

```js
import { NgModule, Optional, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import { REQUEST } from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens';
import { CRAWLER_AGENTS, VIEWER } from './constants';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ /* ... */ ],
  declarations: [ /* ... */ ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: VIEWER,
      useFactory: viewerFactory,
      deps: [PLATFORM_ID, [new Optional(), REQUEST]],
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}

export function viewerFactory(platformId, req: Request): string {
  if (isPlatformBrowser(platformId)) {
    return 'user';
  }
  const userAgent = (req.get('user-agent') || '').toLowerCase();
  const isCrawler = CRAWLER_AGENTS.some(crawlerAgent => userAgent.indexOf(crawlerAgent) !== -1);
  return isCrawler ? 'bot' : 'user';
}
```

Yes, according [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/FactoryProvider#usage-notes) you can pass dependency for provider as an array. We need `Optional` to prevent app crashing on client side. Obviously Express request object doesn't exist there.

Then in your page component you can check viewer like so:

```js
import { Component, Inject, Optional } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-article-page',
  templateUrl: './article-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./article-page.component.scss'],
})
export class ArticlePageComponent {
  constructor(
    @Optional() @Inject(VIEWER) private viewer,
  ) {
    const countViews = this.viewer !== 'bot';
  }
}
```

Please, IF you find my answer helpful, don't forget to mark it as accepted.

Comment: best ever answer! Thank you!!

Comment: req.get does not exist

Solution that worked for me:
const userAgent = (req.headers['user-agent'] || '').toLowerCase();

Comment: Although had a different use case. But it helped to better my solution. Nice